# How to authenticate into a Django app using RemoteUserBackend

Tags: apache, single-sign-on, postman, django-1.9

My app is required to support users logged in via SSO on a 3rd party server.

I configured `settings.py` based on the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/auth-remote-user/), i.e.

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    '...',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.PersistentRemoteUserMiddleware',
    '...',
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.RemoteUserBackend',
]
```

I tried to test this using Postman on a couple of the app's URLs with no auth and with basic auth (user is defined) and, of course, with `REMOTE_USER` (and/or `HTTP_REMOTE_USER` header set).
In all cases I get a `401 - unauthorized` code. Moreover, the breakpoint in `authenticate` is never called. The `process_request` in the middleware is called, but the `REMOTE_USER` header is not in `request.META`.

What else do I need to configure (in Django, Postman - or better still Apache) so that the `REMOTE_USER` will be set?
My knowledge of Apache is minimal, so a link to an example will help a lot.

The closest "solution" I saw is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34168295/optionally-pass-remote-user-to-application), but it seems that the person circumvented the proper way to do this.

**UPDATE**
[image]
The Postman request is simply to one of the basic services which requires users to be logged in (`@login_required` decorator in Django)
I've tried with both basic auth and no auth.
The reply is a 401 without additional information.

```
>curl -i -H 'REMOTE_USER: user' localhost:9000/project/files/
HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized
Date: Sun, 17 Dec 2017 13:38:38 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.10
Expires: Sun, 17 Dec 2017 13:38:38 GMT
Vary: Cookie
Last-Modified: Sun, 17 Dec 2017 13:38:38 GMT
Location: /accounts/login/?next=/project/files/
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Same command with cURL. The Location seems to suggest it tried to redirect to the login page (which should not happen)

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the request? (perhaps the CURL equivalent) And a sample of the response?

Comment: @EdMeacham I updated the question with the Postman query and 401 reply (no details given). Can you point me to an example of how to use REMOTE_USER properly?